# Read and save data file with variable number of columns in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, io

I have a space separated data file that looks like this (just a slice)

```
Wavelength  Ele   Excit   loggf       D0        
11140.324   108.0 3.44     -7.945    4.395
11140.357    26.1 12.09    -2.247
11140.361   108.0 2.39     -8.119    4.395
11140.365    25.0 5.85    -9.734
11140.388    23.0 4.56    -4.573
11140.424   608.0 5.12    -10.419    11.09 
11140.452   606.0 2.12    -11.054     6.25 
11140.496   108.0 2.39    -8.119      4.395
11140.509   606.0 1.70    -7.824      6.25
```

## Part 1

First I would like to read the file a lá `np.loadtxt`. This does not work, so I tried with

```
d = np.genfromtxt('file.dat', skiprows=1, filling_value=0.0, missing_values=' ')
```

and different versions of that. All gave errors: `Line #3 (got 4 columns instead of 5)`. I think I'm close to be able to read the file. Note, that I prefer a solution with something like `np.genfromtxt` rather than openning the file and go through it line by line:

```
with open('test.dat', 'r') as lines:
    for line in lines:
        # put numbers in arrays/lists
```

## Part 2

After reading the file succesfully, I need to save it in a specific format. Very briefly, this file will be a input for a Fotran program, with 10 spaces per column for numbers. Without the last column (`D0`), I can use (there is a column I don't use, hence the `'%27.1f'`)

```
fmt_ = ('%9.2f', '%7.1f', '%11.2f','%10.3f', '%27.1f')
np.savetxt('output.dat', data, fmt=fmt_)
```

But I suspect this wouldn't work either. So s `np.genfromtxt` for saving could be helpful.

Help for it all, one part or just some guidance are appreciated.

Comment: `genfromtxt` is quite happy to accept your line by line input.  It accepts any iterable.  If you give it the file name, it still has to read the file line by line. As for writing, is it ok to write the fill value?

Comment: I still can't get `genfromtxt` to work. Can you show how you do it?
For the writing part, I prefer without the filling values, but I can live with them, and find another way to remove them. In the end, I prefer a simple small program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Part 1:**

Use pandas.  It is designed specifically to handle this sort of scenario:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', sep='\s+')
print(df)
```

gives you:

```
   Wavelength    Ele  Excit   loggf      D0
0   11140.324  108.0   3.44  -7.945   4.395
1   11140.357   26.1  12.09  -2.247     NaN
2   11140.361  108.0   2.39  -8.119   4.395
3   11140.365   25.0   5.85  -9.734     NaN
4   11140.388   23.0   4.56  -4.573     NaN
5   11140.424  608.0   5.12 -10.419  11.090
6   11140.452  606.0   2.12 -11.054   6.250
7   11140.496  108.0   2.39  -8.119   4.395
8   11140.509  606.0   1.70  -7.824   6.250
```

**Part 2**

You can also use pandas for this, although it is a bit more complex to get the formatting correct:

```
formatters  = ['{: >9.2f}'.format, '{: >7.1f}'.format, 
               '{: >11.2f}'.format,'{: >10.3f}'.format, 
               lambda x: ' '*27 if np.isnan(x) else '{: >27.1f}'.format(x)]

lines = df.to_string(index=False, header=False, formatters=formatters)

with open('out.dat', 'w') as outfile:
    outfile.write(lines)
```

Gives you:

```
 11140.32   108.0        3.44     -7.945                         4.4
 11140.36    26.1       12.09     -2.247                            
 11140.36   108.0        2.39     -8.119                         4.4
 11140.36    25.0        5.85     -9.734                            
 11140.39    23.0        4.56     -4.573                            
 11140.42   608.0        5.12    -10.419                        11.1
 11140.45   606.0        2.12    -11.054                         6.2
 11140.50   108.0        2.39     -8.119                         4.4
 11140.51   606.0        1.70     -7.824                         6.2
```

Comment: This works very nicely. Thanks.
Also, a `np.savetxt('out.dat', df.values, fmt=('%9.2f', '%7.1f', '%11.2f','%10.3f', '%27.1f'))` saves the result in the right format. The bonus question is, if there is a way to not save the `NaN` values?

Comment: This will give you a string you can then write, with `NaN` values set to spaces: `df.to_string(index=False, header=False, formatters=['{: >9.2f}'.format, '{: >7.1f}'.format, '{: >11.2f}'.format,'{: >10.3f}'.format, lambda x: ' '*27 if np.isnan(x) else '{: >27.1f}'.format(x)])`

Comment: This works like a charm, and elegant for the problem. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Here's part of a sample run with your data.

```
In [62]: txt=b"""Wavelength  Ele   Excit   loggf       D0        
11140.324   108.0 3.44     -7.945    4.395
...
11140.509   606.0 1.70    -7.824      6.25 """

In [63]: txt=txt.splitlines()

In [64]: def foo(astr):
    # add a 'NaN' field to the short lines
    if len(astr)<35:
        astr += b'  NaN'  # or filler of your choice
    return astr
   ....: 

In [65]: data=np.loadtxt([foo(t) for t in txt], skiprows=1)

In [66]: data
Out[66]: 
array([[  1.11403240e+04,   1.08000000e+02,   3.44000000e+00,
         -7.94500000e+00,   4.39500000e+00],
       [  1.11403570e+04,   2.61000000e+01,   1.20900000e+01,
         -2.24700000e+00,              nan],
        ...
       [  1.11405090e+04,   6.06000000e+02,   1.70000000e+00,
         -7.82400000e+00,   6.25000000e+00]])

In [67]: np.savetxt('test.dat',x,fmt=fmt_)

In [69]: cat test.dat
 11140.32   108.0        3.44     -7.945                         4.4
 11140.36    26.1       12.09     -2.247                         nan
 11140.36   108.0        2.39     -8.119                         4.4
 11140.36    25.0        5.85     -9.734                         nan
 ...
 11140.51   606.0        1.70     -7.824                         6.2
```

The file can be passed through `foo` like this:

```
with open('test.dat') as f: 
     xx = np.loadtxt((foo(t) for t in f),skiprows=1)
```

`savetxt` essentially does a row by row `write`, so it isn't hard to write your own version.  e.g.

```
In [120]: asbytes=np.lib.npyio.asbytes

In [121]: fmt__='%9.2f  %7.1f  %11.2f  %10.3f  %10.1f'

In [122]: with open('test.dat','wb') as f: 
     for row in x:
        f.write(asbytes(fmt__%tuple(row)+'\n'))
   .....:         

In [123]: cat test.dat
 11140.32    108.0         3.44      -7.945         4.4
 11140.36     26.1        12.09      -2.247         nan
 11140.36    108.0         2.39      -8.119         4.4
 11140.36     25.0         5.85      -9.734         nan
 ...
 11140.51    606.0         1.70      -7.824         6.2
```

With this it wouldn't be hard to test each row, and use a different format for rows with a `nan`.